# Is there a way to know when folder has subfolders in Forge API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-bim360

When retrieving folders contents using the Autodesk Forge API `GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents` endpoint or using the `GetFolderContentsAsync` method in the `Autodesk.Forge.FoldersApi` C# client respectively, it looks like there is no way of telling, whether a folder can be expanded = has any subfolders.

A round trip to the server and retrieving the folder contents is required for each folder in the collection to see if any subfolders exist. Is there a better way to do that which would not be so inefficient? Something like a flag in the `GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents` return payload?

Comment: This issue is now tracked as **AUT-137** in our internal systems.

Answer (score 0):

The `/contents/` endpoint returns a list, for each list item, if `"type":"folders"` you can look at `.attributes.objectCount` property, which indicates if that folder contains objects.

Comment: We found `.attributes.objectCount` returning negative values in many cases, where such negative value could be found both for empty and non-empty folders.

Comment: for those folders with a negative value, what do you have on the folder? That will help investigate what's happening.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. One folder is empty, the other one has both sheets and one subfolder in it. There is no pattern, actually... I can send more details to Mikako if that would help investigating.

Comment: Yes, please send, and mention this stackoverflow question (link)

Comment: I sent more details to Mikako last Friday. However something struck me just now @augusto-goncalves - if `.attributes.objectCount` - when functioning properly - has been designed to return number of _objects_ in a folder it would still not help my case, unless only another folder can be counted towards this count. I believe that files and/or sheets would count as objects as well though. How is it supposed to work?